# Sqlite :Update query is not updating value to database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, adapter

I try to update local database using update query while clicking in this increment button.this function is in baseadapter. during a long press in the listview a listview popup will occur there iam need trying to call this function to update Qty in database .
sqlite database is used .

```
 holder.mPlusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            count[0]++;
            holder.sSelectQty.setText(String.valueOf(count[0]));

            descriptionDb.UpdateDescQty(mData[position][0],String.valueOf(count[0])); // to update incremented value to the datdabase

        }
    });
```

In updatequery used to update

```
  public void UpdateDescQty(String ItemID, String Qty) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Qty(), Qty)


        String[] args = new String[]{ItemID};
        database.update(TableName, values,Id() + "=?", args);

}
```

I tried this method also to updated

```
database.update(TableName(),values,  " "+cId()+"="+ ItemID, null);
```

There is no any error but it is not entry value in to the database,

Comment: What's `QsDatabaseHelper.getDescDescQty()` returning? The naming suggests it is not a column name to be used with `ContentValues`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
public void UpdateDescQty(String item_id, String qty) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(QsDatabaseHelper.getDescDescQty(), qty);
        database.update(QsDatabaseHelper.getDescTableName(),
        values,sDatabaseHelper.getDescDescId() + " = "+item_id, null);

    }
```

**SYNTAX**

```
update(Tablename, ContentValues Object, "Primary_Key=" + Prinary_key_value, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the mistake.

Code working perfectly but i didnt settext where qty is displaying .

```
 holder.sSelectQty.setText(VALUE FROM DATABASE);
```

Comment: Add validation there. `isEmpty()`